# How do I create a simple function to plot data in Python using matplot.lib?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)
y=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)
def Exercise3(x,y):
    plt.title('Different Simulation')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength Nm')
    plt.ylabel('Global irradiance W/m²')
    plt.legend(['UTC0800', 'UTC0930'])
    plt.axis([280,400,0,1200])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(x,y,'r--')
    plt.savefig('exercise.png' ,format='png' , dpi = 1200)
    plt.close()  
    plt.show()    
Exercise3(x,y)
```

I want to create a simple function for plotting the data in different Figures using the same function. For example in my code if I call function "Exercise3"it should plot the data stored in x and y. I want to customize the function "Exercise3" such that if I change the values in x, y the function should return me a new figure with different legends, title and figure name. So that I have the old plots also before changing the variable values. I am at early stages of learning coding, I don't know if such code is even possible. The values for x and y should be in indented in function or outside?

Comment: please paste your code as text and not as a picture, so that everybody can test it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to the community, have edited the post completely hoping to get some hint and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I kind of don't get your question, I am learning too, I ended up with this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  7 15:53:53 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864268/how-do-i-create-a-simple-function-to-plot-data-in-python-using-matplot-lib

"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)
# y=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)

x1=np.fromstring('100 200 300', dtype=int, sep=' ')
y1=np.fromstring('100 400 600', dtype=int, sep=' ')
             

x2=np.fromstring('50 100 150', dtype=int, sep=' ')
y2=np.fromstring('200 600 1000', dtype=int, sep=' ')

def Exercise3(*args):
    plt.title('Different Simulation')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength Nm')
    plt.ylabel('Global irradiance W/m²')
    plt.legend(['UTC0800', 'UTC0930'])
    plt.axis([100,400,0,1200])
    plt.grid(True)
    # for i in args:
    for count,i in enumerate(*args):
        print(i)
        x = i[0]
        print(x, type(x))
        y = i[1]
        print(y, type(y))
       
        plt.plot(i[0],i[1], label=str(count))
        
        # plt.savefig('exercise.png' ,format='png' , dpi = 1200)
        # plt.close()  
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()    


a = (x1,y1)

b = (x2,y2)

c = (x1,y2)

arguments = a,b,c

Exercise3(arguments)
```

[image: output]

or just with one series of data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)
# y=np.loadtxt(#data stored on local drive)

x1=np.fromstring('100 200 300 350 400', dtype=int, sep=' ')
y1=np.fromstring('100 400 600 700 750', dtype=int, sep=' ')
             

def Exercise3(x,y):
    plt.title('Different Simulation')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength Nm')
    plt.ylabel('Global irradiance W/m²')
    plt.legend(['UTC0800', 'UTC0930'])
    plt.axis([80,400,0,1200])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(x,y,'r--')
    plt.savefig('exercise.png' ,format='png' , dpi = 1200) 
    plt.show()    
    
    
Exercise3(x1,y1)
```

output:

[image]

but in this case your code was already good